# Merge lists is multiple columns of a pandas dataframe into a sigle list in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns containing lists. I want to combine these columns into a single column and merge the lists into a single list. Also this list should only contain unique values from the original lists.

I've tried merging them using `df['E']=df[['B','C']].values.tolist()`.

However this creates a single column with values comprising two lists.

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
A       B       C       D
a1      [b1,b2] [c1,b1] d1
a2      [b1,b1] [b3]    d2
a3      [b2]    [b2,b2] d3
```

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
A       B       C       D       E
a1      [b1,b2] [c1,b1] d1      [b1,b2,c1]
a2      [b1,b1] [b3]    d2      [b1,b3]
a3      [b2]    [b2,b2] d3      [b2]
```

Edit: The values within the lists of the dataframe are strings.

Comment: look into `set`

Comment: @jpp I've added a clarification to the question. The lists within the dataframe are strings and hence the provided solutions were not working. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['E']=(df.B+df.C).map(set).map(list)
df
Out[81]: 
    A         B         C   D             E
0  a1  [b1, b2]  [c1, b1]  d1  [b2, b1, c1]
1  a2  [b1, b1]      [b3]  d2      [b3, b1]
2  a3      [b2]  [b2, b2]  d3          [b2]
```

Comment: @jpp I got it working. However do you know of a way to show the dataframe without empty list in column. I'm looking for something like: df = df[df['E']!=[]]

Comment: `df.E=df.E.where(df.E.astype(bool),'')` @Mohnish

Comment: Do you know how I can drop a particular value from a list within the datafame cell?

Comment: @Mohnish this is another question , you may check list.remove

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.fromkeys) within a list comprehension. Note by your choice of lists within series you are losing all vectorisation benefits.

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
                   'B': [['b1', 'b2'], ['b1', 'b1'], ['b2']],
                   'C': [['c1', 'b1'], ['b3'], ['b2', 'b2']],
                   'D': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']})

df['E'] = [list(dict.fromkeys(chain(x, y))) for x, y in zip(df['B'], df['C'])]

print(df)

    A         B         C   D             E
0  a1  [b1, b2]  [c1, b1]  d1  [b1, b2, c1]
1  a2  [b1, b1]      [b3]  d2      [b1, b3]
2  a3      [b2]  [b2, b2]  d3          [b2]
```

The benefit of this method in Python v3.7+ (and unofficially in v3.6 as a CPython implementation detail) is ordering is preserved, as dictionaries are insertion-ordered.

Comment: Sure, the lists within your example dataframe also contain strings. If your dataframe is different, [post a new question defining your dataframe precisely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

If order does not matter, [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['a1', ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'b1'], 'd1'],
        ['a2', ['b1', 'b1'], ['b3'], 'd2'],
        ['a3', ['b2'], ['b2', 'b2'], 'd3']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])


def uniques(xs):
    return list(set(xi for x in xs for xi in x))


df['E'] = df[['B', 'C']].apply(uniques, axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    A         B         C   D             E
0  a1  [b1, b2]  [c1, b1]  d1  [b1, b2, c1]
1  a2  [b1, b1]      [b3]  d2      [b1, b3]
2  a3      [b2]  [b2, b2]  d3          [b2]
```

If order does matter use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

data = [['a1', ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'b1'], 'd1'],
        ['a2', ['b1', 'b1'], ['b3'], 'd2'],
        ['a3', ['b2'], ['b2', 'b2'], 'd3']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])


def uniques(xs):
    return list(OrderedDict().fromkeys(xi for x in xs for xi in x))


df['E'] = df[['B', 'C']].apply(uniques, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
    A         B         C   D             E
0  a1  [b1, b2]  [c1, b1]  d1  [b1, b2, c1]
1  a2  [b1, b1]      [b3]  d2      [b1, b3]
2  a3      [b2]  [b2, b2]  d3          [b2]
```